# Passing arguments to service in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

What I want to do is this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    image: redis-test
    entrypoint: /app/src/main.rb
    working_dir: /app
    links:
      - redis
  redis:
    image: redis
    args:
      - appendonly=yes
```

When I run `docker-compose up` it complains:

> Unsupported config option for services.redis: 'args'

Is this possible?

**EDIT**

More context: http://redis.io/topics/persistence#append-only-file

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this using `command`, but first you need to take a look at what the default command is in the [redis Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/bc3ca850f4a2a2e9e5d4b3b8272e5536b4d21d24/3.0/Dockerfile#L51).

This should work for you:

```
redis:
  image: redis
  command: redis-server --appendonly yes
```